# Access object of a class from other classes

Tags: c#, class

I realise this is probably a very simple question and will be answered in no time. But wondering what to do. I have a class called Budget with an object named 'user01' I would basically like to be able to access that object across multiple classes, similar to the code below.

Main

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Budget user01 = new Budget(1000);
    }
```

Budget Class

```
class Budget
{
    private int _budget;

    public Budget(int budget)
    {
        _budget = budget;
    }

    public int UserBudget
    {
        get { return _budget; }
        set { _budget = value; }
    }
}
```

Expense Class

```
class Expenses
{
    // What I've been trying to do...
    public int Something(user01.budget)
    {
        user01.budget - 100;
        return user01.budget;
    }
}
```

I'm not really sure where to go from here, and am hoping to a little help/explanation. Many thanks

Comment: Is that C with Classes?

Comment: C#, Sorry messed up on the tags @MOehm

Comment: Okay. Not for me, then.

Comment: Afaik `main` has to be in a class as well; you could make the object a public property of that class and then simply access it from other classes like so: `MainClass.budget01`.

Answer (score 1):

This is invalid:

```
public int Something(user01.budget)
```

But you *can* supply an instance of a `Budget` object to that method:

```
public int Something(Budget budget)
{
    budget.UserBudget -= 100;
    return budget.UserBudget;
}
```

Then you can invoke that method from your consuming code:

```
Budget user01 = new Budget(1000);
Expenses myExpenses = new Expenses();
int updatedBudget = myExpenses.Something(user01);
```

The method doesn't "access the variable `user01`".  However, when you call the method, you *supply it* with your `user01` instance.  Inside of the method, the supplied instance in this case is referenced by the local `budget` variable.  Any time you call the method and give it any instance of a `Budget`, for that one time that instance will be referenced by that local variable.

Go ahead and step through this using your debugger and you should get a much clearer picture of what's going on when you call a method.

(Note that your naming here is a bit unintuitive, which is probably adding to the confusion.  Is your object a "budget" or is it a "user"?  Clearly defining and naming your types and variables goes a *long way* to making code easier to write.)

Answer (score 1):

Its a pretty simple change to your Expenses class:

```
class Expenses
{
    // What I've been trying to do...
    public int Something(Budget userBudget)
    {
        userBudget.UserBudget -= 100;
        return userBudget.UserBudget;
    }
}
```

Which you then call like this from your main class:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Budget user01 = new Budget(1000);
    Expenses expenses = new Expenses();
    var result = expenses.Something(user01);
}
```

Or, if you make your Something method `static` you can call it without an instance:

```
class Expenses
{
    // What I've been trying to do...
    public static int Something(Budget userBudget)
    {
        userBudget.UserBudget -= 100;
        return userBudget.UserBudget;
    }
}
```

Which you call like this:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Budget user01 = new Budget(1000);
    var result = Expenses.Something(user01);
}
```

Its important when designing methods to remember that a method takes in a general argument and its the *caller* that passes in something specific.